# Lazy loaded module create multiples instance of the parent service each time is loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Every time I navigate from `MainComponent` to `TestListComponent` the TestListComponent constructor is triggered and a new instance of the `ObservableService`is created. When I click the link the console show the duplicated messages. Maybe is an angular issue, any help?

> main.module.ts

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
    import {MainRoutingModule} from "./main-routing.module"; 
    import {MainComponent}   from './main.component';  
    import {ObservableService} from "../../core/services/observable.service";

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            MainRoutingModule,                   
        ],
        declarations: [MainComponent],
        providers: [ObservableService],
        bootstrap: [
            MainComponent
        ]
    })
    export class MainModule { }
```

> main.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'tests', loadChildren: 'angular/app/modules/test-list/test-list.module#TestListModule'},
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MainRoutingModule {}
```

> observable.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Rx";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'


@Injectable()
export class ObservableService {

    // Observable string sources
    private changeLanguageStatus = new Subject<Object>();

    // Observable string streams
    changeLanguageStatus$ = this.changeLanguageStatus.asObservable();

    constructor(){}

    /**
     * Change language event
     * @param params
     */
    changeLanguageEvent(params: Object){
        this.changeLanguageStatus.next(params);
    }        
}
```

> test-list.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';       
import {TestListComponent} from "./test-list.component";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        TestListComponent
    ]
})
export class TestListModule {}
```

> test-list.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {ObservableService} from "../../core/services/observable.service";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'st-test-list',
    templateUrl: 'test-list.component.html'
})

export class TestListComponent {

    constructor(private observableService:ObservableService) {
        observableService.changeLanguageStatus$.subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log('Test', data);
            });
    }    
}
```

> main.component.ts

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import {ObservableService} from "../../core/services/observable.service"; 

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'st-main',
    templateUrl: 'main.component.html'       
})

export class MainComponent {      
   constructor(private observableService:ObservableService) {} 

   changeLanguage(lang){
      this.observableService.changeLanguageEvent({type: lang});
   }  
}
```

> main.component.html

```
<a href="" (click)="changeLanguage('en')"></a>

<!--Dynamic content-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: It might be related to this issue  -https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12869

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be expected behavior that when you navigate to a component via routing it is created and when you navigate back it is destroyed. As far as I know you are experiencing this issue because you are creating what is called an Infinite Observable i.e. you are subscribing to it and waiting for a stream of events, in your case changing language. Because you never unsubscribe from your Observable, the function subscribed to it is kept alive for each new instance of your component. Therefore, rxjs won't handle disposing of your subscription and you will have to do it yourself.

First off I'd suggest you read about Lifecycle hooks. Check out the OnInit and OnDestroy lifecycle hooks.

Use ngOnInit to subscribe to your Observable and use ngOnDestroy to unsubscribe from it as such:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({ .... })

export class TestListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{ 
    private _languageSubscription : Subscription;

    ngOnInit(): void 
    {
        this._languageSubscription = observableService.changeLanguageStatus$.subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log('Test', data);
        }); 
    }

    ngOnDestroy() : void 
    {
        this._languageSubscription.unsubscribe();   
    }

}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.